# Rainloop - How to access DKIM and other header information in the Message View

Tags: webmail

I have a heavily modified Rainloop install.  Figured out a lot of ways to modify it, but having the following issue:

Rainloop shows a DKIM signature indicator (with it's own interpretation) as a green checkmark.

If you hover your mouse pointer over it (when shown), it will show a "tool-tip" of the text in that header.

The problem here is, on mobile you can't "hover", generally speaking.  How can I access the header data via JS, or how can I talk to the element for the "tool-tip" for the DKIM header info so I can put a click-listener on the indicator?

It's nice they show it on the mouse-over, but I can't seem to find any way to reference it.

In addition, it would be really grand to show that info in the "info" expandable box.

This is all pertaining to the Message View in Rainloop specifically.

Really nice program.  But there is no documentation on their API.

Anyone have ideas on this?  I can't seem to get a handle on it through devtools.

If I could just get a solid CSS selector to reference it by that would be grand.

All I seem to be coming up with on searches are similar expressions.

Hoping maybe someone on Stack might have found a clue on this, because DKIM is important, and ordinary users need simple indications as to trust.

This is something to help other people, not just me, so if anyone has a way can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  So right after I posted, I did find it.  Not sure how I missed it before, but the dkim results header data can be found in the "dkim icon"'s title attribute-- the "icon" is an  tag (rainloop hijacks the  tag as UTF8 icon containers).

So the tooltip apparently is an actual tooltip, whereas I thought it was something like a hidden div being shown on a mouse-over.

I wonder if there is a way to get it to show on a click instead of a hover (preferably using CSS).